# ios: protect Strings or include specific file in compilation

Tags: ios, encryption, data-protection

I face the following problem: I have a bunch of NSStrings in one of my .m files and I don't won't users to access them (which can easily be done with jailbreak and strings tool etc).

I thought about encrypting the NSStrings - but then I'll get some NSData which has to be saved in a file. I think I'll have the following two problems then:

1. The encrypted file is accessible via the bundle.
2. The encryption key is also a NSString in my source code

Can I add the encrypted files to the compiler so that they will become a part of the application? And is there a way to protect my encryption key?

Comment: Please see this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt them using your own algorithm and then decrypt them when you need them. Instead of a key, you will have as well the algorithm...